# Anchoring Buttons To Make Full Screen Application

Tags: vb.net, button, visual-studio-2013

I'll get straight into it. I have 3 buttons and 3 labels lay out like this on my winforms application form:

[image: Normal Size View]

When he user makes the form full screen, I want the label to stay the same, and the buttons to become wider. I also want them to spread out equally, like this:
[image: Maximized View]

I set the anchor property of the buttons to Top, Left, Right and when I make the application full screen, the buttons become very long and overlap each other. If I set the anchor property to Top, Right, the end up exactly the same but on the right side of the screen.
What is the best way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you to try and move the Label-Button pairs into separate `Panels`. That allows you to resize the panels as one entity on the form and, for example, simply set the the anchoring of buttons to resize with the panel they are in.

<s>It's very hard to tell what exactly you want to achieve by your description. Include two screenshots in your question that show the position and size of the non maximized form and the desired positions and sizes in the maximized form. That way it's easier to see what you really want.</s>

Together with the `Panel` you should use a `TableLayoutPanel` with the number of columns equal to the number of your buttons.
Edit the columns of the tablelayout to have percentage numbers as `Width` (e.g. 33.33% for each column when you use 3 columns).

[image]

Add a panel to your form. Place a Label and a Button inside and anchor the button to the left and right and the label only to the left. Drag the panel into one of the table columns and set it's `Dock` to Fill. Then finally set the anchor of the tablelayoutpanel to left+right to make it resize with the form.

What happens now is:

1. The form resizes
2. The Tablelayout resizes with the form
3. The columns of the table resize with the table
4. The panel resizes with the column
5. The button inside resizes with the panel

Do this for the other table columns as well and you are golden.

**Small form**
[image]

**Large form**
[image]