# How to make VB.NET application full screen without moving my controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to make my application so that when it has been maximized the control will automatically position itself it the right place.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anchoring Buttons To Make Full Screen Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578843/anchoring-buttons-to-make-full-screen-application)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a WinForm project, you need to set the `Anchor` property of the button to `Bottom, Right`.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't completely put it in the corner

Comment: @PrestonL After you set the anchor property, you still need to move the button to the desired location in the designer (relative to the bottom-right corner).

Comment: Okay it works, but how would I make a picture box or something get bigger when maximized?

Comment: @PrestonL By anchoring it to all four sides.

Comment: That would make the picture box fullscreen. I just want it to be a bigger when form is maximized

Comment: @PrestonL It only makes it full screen if it's fills the whole form when the form is small too.

Comment: @PrestonL, we can't read your mind. The `Anchor` property does what it does, i.e. it keeps the same distance between one or more edges of a child control and its parent. If you want something other than that then you'll have to explain what it is.  I would suggest that you [read this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?630636-Anchor-amp-Dock-For-Automatic-Resizing) first and then, if you still don't know how to achieve your aim, explain to us EXACTLY what your aim is.

Answer (score 0):

The most useful control is the TableLayoutPanel. You should put all the controls on the panel -> set dock: Full and every time the form resized, the controls stay in their container.